# How to deselect a draggable svg element in Vue?

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

I am trying to implement a drag and drop feature in Vue using SVG, and I am able to click on a shape and it moves along with the mouse; however, I cannot quite figure out how to deselect the shape so that it is placed on the coordinates where I issue a double click event. Here is my Vue instance:

```
new Vue ({
 el: '#meow',
 data: {
    x: '',
    y: '',
    rects: [
      {x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150, fill: 'black'}
    ]
 },
 methods: {
   moveHandler () {
      this.$refs.rct[0].setAttribute('transform',   `translate(${this.x-100}, ${this.y-100})`)
},
 selectRect (e, idx) {
   let temp = this.$refs.rct[idx]
   this.$refs.wb.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler)
   this.$refs.wb.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
   temp.removeAttribute('transform') // should I remove the transform attribute?
   })
},
 getMousePositionOnCanvas (e) {
   var mousePos = this.getCoordinates(this.$refs.wb, e);
   this.x = mousePos.x
   this.y = mousePos.y
 },
 getCoordinates (canvas, evt) {
   const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
   return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
   }
 }
}
})
```

For a working demo: please see https://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/gGwEQQ?editors=1010 As you can see, if I double click on the location I want to place the shape, the shape still moves with my mouse. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you were super close. Your object was being placed on double click but the event still existed when the mouse moved so it would call that function again to drag it. What you need to do is remove that event.

Here is a code snippet and a code pen for you.

```
selectRect (e, idx) {
  let temp = this.$refs.rct[idx]
  this.$refs.wb.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler)
   this.$refs.wb.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
      this.$refs.wb.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler)
  })
},
```

https://codepen.io/potatogopher/pen/pWEMzg?editors=1011